# Gitlab Release json web access

Tags: github, gitlab

GitHub has a public api that one can access to get current release info, and find the release file (.deb or .tar.gz or .exe, etc) by going to [https://api.github.com/repos/[project](https://api.github.com/repos/%5Bproject) creator]/[project]/releases/latest

Does GitLab have something similar?  I'm working on an automated installer to get certain programs from GitLab that have releases.  Using the above api for GitHub, I'm able to get the json info for the current release, and get the url to download the latest release, based on what version I want.

I'm hoping to find something similar in GitLab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look no further than [GitLab's Release API Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/releases/) to start that investigation. It looks quite robust, and I believe you will find it can provide that information.

You can use this API to query for each project, looking for the releases it has. (You could also look for the availability of the project if you are unsure if it is present). Once found, determine the release to retrieve. It's important to note that releases are not always made by a team, so they hopefully are specifically packaging the code into a release for distribution. Additionally, via the API, you can also ensure that the release has specific tags so that if they are using tags, you can focus on specific ones of note, or you can use a more generic approach (e.g. semantic version) to determine which release to retrieve.

Hope that helps. GitLab has a rich API. Take a look.

Comment: Shame on me for not even trying...  because the api was specifying a personal access token, I skipped over just trying it... sure enough, if you go to https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/[project id]/releases  you get exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: It happens. No worries. Glad you found it!